# SQL: check if a table contains no nulls in a particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, exists, not-exists

I'm working on a stored procedure and at one point I want to check my table variable to see if there are exactly zero rows with a specific field equal null. In other words, for every row in my table, this field has a non-null value.  I'd like to not do it by checking count(), but by using EXISTS.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM @sometable where somefield IS NULL ) 
       SET @somefield = @somefield /* just a way to skip this */
ELSE
       /* perform some logic */
```

Now I know I can use NOT EXISTS, but I assume a NOT EXISTS is much slower than an EXISTS. I swear I read something recently (on SO I think) that had an example of how to do what I want to do with one Exists clause but I can't find it and neglected to bookmark it. Though maybe I'm mistaken.

The reason I set up an if/else is because from my understanding EXISTS will return before a NOT EXISTS and since this is a pretty intensive stored procedure (called quite frequently and sometimes in bulk) I'm hoping to save some processing here.

Maybe I'm looking at this all wrong or assuming something incorrectly. I'm here to learn so point me in the right direction if I've got it all wrong.

Edit: Apparently there is no difference in this context (not part of a where clause/subquery). But suppose I WERE using exists in a where clause and wanted to check for the exact scenario above (ALL non-null values in a field) particularly when the table in question could potentially have thousands of rows. [kind of new to SO, if I should post this as its own question, please let me know]

Comment: An **all** non-null values check in the where clause of a main query is essentially the same context, since it will only be executed once per query. An all non-null values check in a sub-query is a very bad idea, since it will require a table scan of the relevant table every time the sub-query is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both EXISTS or NOT EXISTS in this format will stop when they find a row and give true/false as appropriate.

The IF will jump accordingly and there îs not much to optimise here...

Comment: when you say "this format" are you referring to  the fact that its not part of a where clause in a query?  If so, (I know its a totally different question) what would be the difference there?

Comment: Sorry yes, not part of a subquery. They can give different results in some queries if you have IF EXISTS(SELECT WHERE EXISTS()) with NOTs here and there

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS` and `EXISTS` should take the same amount of time. Either one can be derived by first computing the other and negating the result.

Comment: In his example, wouldn't we expect `NOT EXISTS` to take longer because of the underlying logic (he will be looking for a `NOT NULL` on all rows instead of a `NULL` on a single row).

Comment: @JNK: No - if there is no NULL on any record, either version of the query will have to check every record in the table, whereas if there is a NULL anywhere, both queries will run until the first NULL is found.

Comment: @JNK: `NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @sometable WHERE something IS NOT NULL)` tests that *every* row is null, which is not the same thing at all.